# Best way to merge two Arrays of Classes based on Class variable value

Tags: java, arrays

Using Java which is the best way to merge two arrays of class based on some value of the class?

Example, We have these two Classes:

```
public class C1{
  public String id="";
  public String value="";
  public String tot="";
}

public Class C2{
 public String id="";
 public String tot="";
}
```

And in some point of our code we have two Arrays like:

```
            //id -value - tot
C1 a [] = { {"1","value#1",""}, 
            {"2","value#2",""}, 
            {"3","value#3",""}, 
            {"4","value#4",""}
    };
                //id - tot
    C2 b [] = { {"1","2"}, 
                {"2","11"}, 
                {"4","15"}
};
```

The final array should be like:

```
C1 f [] = { {"1","value#1","2"}, 
            {"2","value#2","11"}, 
            {"3","value#3",""}, 
            {"4","value#4","15"}
};
```

I'm trying to figure out the best  way to achieve this result without reading one or another array from start to end, because here the two arrays have only few rows, but in reality they both can have a length of 100k+...

Comment: Sort the arrays by the key.  Go through the arrays by increasing key, comparing to see if they match, and if they do then use reflection to copy all of the attributes of C2 to C1.

Comment: Above comment is a nice solution but I think the reflection is overkill unless for some reason you don't know what fields need to be copied at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put one array in a `Map<String, C1>` where the key is the `id`. Iterate through the other array looking for the `id` in the map and updating the value. If you use a `TreeHashMap` you can get the values back out in order by the keys.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a text-book example of something you would do distributed with hadoop and map-reduce. Depending on what your level of ambition and your budget is here (and how time-critical this operation is) it might be worth-while to look into.

Answer (score 0):

This is something database engines are doing for living. Lets see how they doing it:
a) to join very small dataset with other one - nested loops are used. It is least efficient way. 
b) If one set is small enough to fit in memory - you can put its as key-value pairs in the hashmap and then do one path over smaller data set to find all matches. 
c) If arrays are sorted by key - you can do merger-sort join. You simply get over both dataset and looking for the matches. If one array is already sorted - it might make sense to sort the second one and then use this algorithm. 
d) If both dataset are too big to fit a memory - you can use grace hash join. You divide both datasets into X buckets by hashing their join key. If you use the same hash function then you can be sure that you only have to join corresponding buckets. Then you use any of the above techniques to join buckets.
e) Hadoop and Map/Reduce is good option, if you have really big data sets. Internally it will sort both datasets and then let you to do the join.
f) You can take Hadoop with Hive, simply put data into its table and let it to do the join. I see this option as most practical for big data volumes.